# How to judge if a RDD will load into ram ？

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

A example of http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2014/EECS-2014-12.pdf as follows.

```
lines = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
errors = lines.filter(_.startsWith("ERROR"))
errors.persist()
```

The thesis sys: "***Note that the base RDD, lines, is not loaded into RAM. This is desirable because the
error messages might only be a small fraction of the data (small enough to fit into
memory)***"

My question is How to judge if a RDD will load into ram ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not correct. The RDD would be loaded into RAM if you would tell the engine to do so, the engine won't complain about your code. To make it just mark the RDD as to be cached with `cache()` or `persist()` and then call an action on it - it would be cached.

Correct one is "how to judge whether to cache RDD or not?". The RDD should be cached if:

1. You plan to run series of actions on top of this data
2. This data is expensive to recompute. It might be some result of intense computations, joins, etc.

If the data is really expensive to recompute, you might consider persisting it not only in memory, but use MEMORY_AND_DISK persistence level - this way even if you don't have enough RAM instead of evicting RDD partitions and recomputing them later the engine will put them on the HDDs. Also you might consider persisting the data to storage in this case, for instance with `saveAsSequenceFile()`

In this specific case `lines` RDD was not cached because it is used only once, it is big and it can be easily re-read from the storage. While `errors` RDD is computed one and small and in the future they plan to run series of actions on top of it, so it is good to cache it

Comment: As you said, "In this specific case lines RDD was not cached because it is used only once, it is big and it can be easily re-read from the storage. While errors RDD is computed one and small and in the future they plan to run series of actions on top of it, so it is good to cache it", what's spark's logic to know lines didn't not to cache and errors should cache??

Comment: Spark does not have this kind of logic. If you add the second line `lines.cache()`, then it would be cached. If you won't add this, it won't be cached